# Is it possible to show vertex information in tables in VS2012 like in PIX?

Tags: debugging, pix

In PIX I was able to watch the objects' vertex data at different stages in tables, like before vertex shader, between vertex and pixel shaders, and so on. Can you see this in Visual Studio 2012 graphics debugger? I mean, you can see the data as a list of sorts, but it's impossible to get a good overview of that if you have more than like 3 vertices.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, the list-based PostVS functionality is completely gone from VSPix. All you can get is a small wireframe image from the pipeline stages.

You can modify your code to use stream-output via [CreateGeometryShaderWithStreamOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as a non-generic workaround hack to store the intermediary results into a buffer and read that back CPU-side. It's intrusive, but it might just be enough for those situations where you really need the data.